# R glmer warnings: model fails to converge / model is nearly unidentifiable

Tags: r, warnings, mixed-models

I have seen questions about this on this forum, and I have also asked it myself in a previous post but I still haven't been able to solve my problem. Therefore I am trying again, formulating the question as clearly as I can this time, with as much detailed information as possible.

My data set has a binomial dependent variable, 3 categorical fixed effects and 2 categorical random effects (item and subject). I am using a mixed effects model using glmer. Here is what I entered in R:

```
modelall<- glmer(moodR ~ group*context*condition + (1|subject) + ``(1|item), data=RprodHSNS, family="binomial")`
```

I get 2 warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.02081 (tol = 0.001, component 11)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
- Rescale variables?`
```

My summary looks like this:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: moodR ~ group * context * condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
Data: RprodHSNS`


AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
1400.0   1479.8   -686.0   1372.0     2195 `

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.0346 -0.2827 -0.0152  0.2038 20.6578 `

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
item    (Intercept) 1.475    1.215   
subject (Intercept) 1.900    1.378   
Number of obs: 2209, groups:  item, 54; subject, 45
Fixed effects:`
Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)`                             
(Intercept)                -0.61448   42.93639  -0.014 0.988582  
group1                     -1.29254   42.93612  -0.030 0.975984    
context1                    0.09359   42.93587   0.002 0.998261   
context2                   -0.77262    0.22894  -3.375 0.000739***
condition1                  4.99219   46.32672   0.108 0.914186
group1:context1            -0.17781   42.93585  -0.004 0.996696
group1:context2            -0.10551    0.09925  -1.063 0.287741
group1:condition1          -3.07516   46.32653  -0.066 0.947075
context1:condition1        -3.47541   46.32648  -0.075 0.940199
context2:condition1        -0.07293    0.22802  -0.320 0.749087
group1:context1:condition1  2.47882   46.32656   0.054 0.957328
group1:context2:condition1  0.30360    0.09900   3.067 0.002165 **

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) group1 cntxt1 cntxt2 cndtn1 grp1:cnt1 grp1:2 grp1:cnd1 cnt1:1 cnt2:1 g1:1:1
group1      -1.000                                                                            
context1    -1.000  1.000                                                                
context2     0.001  0.000 -0.001                                                              
condition1  -0.297  0.297  0.297  0.000                                                       
grp1:cntxt1  1.000 -1.000 -1.000  0.001 -0.297                                                
grp1:cntxt2  0.001  0.000  0.000 -0.123  0.000  0.000                                       
grp1:cndtn1  0.297 -0.297 -0.297 -0.001 -1.000  0.297     0.000                               
cntxt1:cnd1  0.297 -0.297 -0.297 -0.001 -1.000  0.297     0.001  1.000                        
cntxt2:cnd1  0.000  0.000 -0.001  0.011  0.001  0.000    -0.197 -0.001    -0.001              
grp1:cnt1:1 -0.297  0.297  0.297  0.001  1.000 -0.297    -0.001 -1.000    -1.000  0.001       
grp1:cnt2:1  0.000  0.000  0.001 -0.198  0.000 -0.001     0.252  0.000     0.001 -0.136  0.000
```

Extremely high p-values, which does not seem to be possible.

In a previous post I read that one of the problems could be fixed by increasing the amount of iterations by inserting the following in the command: glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000))

So that's what I did:

```
modelall<- glmer(moodR ~ group*context*condition + (1|subject) + (1|item), data=RprodHSNS, family="binomial", glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

Now, the second warning is gone, but the first one is still there:

```
> Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.005384 (tol = 0.001, component 7)
```

The summary also still looks odd:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: moodR ~ group * context * condition + (1 | subject) + (1 | item)
   Data: RprodHSNS
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))`

AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
1400.0   1479.8   -686.0   1372.0     2195

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.0334 -0.2827 -0.0152  0.2038 20.6610 

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
item    (Intercept) 1.474    1.214   
subject (Intercept) 1.901    1.379   
Number of obs: 2209, groups:  item, 54; subject, 45

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -0.64869   26.29368  -0.025 0.980317    
group1                     -1.25835   26.29352  -0.048 0.961830    
context1                    0.12772   26.29316   0.005 0.996124    
context2                   -0.77265    0.22886  -3.376 0.000735 ***
condition1                  4.97325   22.80050   0.218 0.827335    
group1:context1            -0.21198   26.29303  -0.008 0.993567    
group1:context2            -0.10552    0.09924  -1.063 0.287681    
group1:condition1          -3.05629   22.80004  -0.134 0.893365    
context1:condition1        -3.45656   22.80017  -0.152 0.879500    
context2:condition1        -0.07305    0.22794  -0.320 0.748612    
group1:context1:condition1  2.45996   22.80001   0.108 0.914081    
group1:context2:condition1  0.30347    0.09899   3.066 0.002172 ** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) group1 cntxt1 cntxt2 cndtn1 grp1:cnt1 grp1:2 grp1:cnd1 cnt1:1 cnt2:1 g1:1:1
group1      -1.000                                                                            
context1    -1.000  1.000                                                                     
context2     0.000  0.000  0.000                                                              
condition1   0.123 -0.123 -0.123 -0.001                                                       
grp1:cntxt1  1.000 -1.000 -1.000  0.001  0.123                                                
grp1:cntxt2  0.001  0.000  0.000 -0.123  0.001  0.000                                         
grp1:cndtn1 -0.123  0.123  0.123  0.000 -1.000 -0.123    -0.001                               
cntxt1:cnd1 -0.123  0.123  0.123  0.000 -1.000 -0.123     0.000  1.000                        
cntxt2:cnd1  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.011 -0.001  0.000    -0.197  0.001     0.001              
grp1:cnt1:1  0.123 -0.123 -0.123  0.000  1.000  0.123     0.000 -1.000    -1.000 -0.001      
grp1:cnt2:1  0.000 -0.001  0.001 -0.198  0.001 -0.001     0.252 -0.001     0.000 -0.136  0.000
```

What I can do to solve this? Or can anyone tell me what this warning even means? (in a way that an R-newbie like myself can understand) Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're seeing very strong correlations among fixed-effect parameters (e.g. `group1` vs `context1`.  This is probably some combination of complete separation and perfect multicollinearity.  Look for a combination of fixed-effect parameters that has all zero or all one responses ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ben. I have no idea how the fixed effects can be so correlated. When I look at my data this doesn't seem to be the case at all. Is it possible that the R output is not correct/ cannot be interpreted correctly due to the warning, and that therefore I get those correlations that do not make sense?